# special character causing python csv script to fail

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file where one of the cells has this weird arrow character in it:

[image]

No matter what I do I cannot seem to strip it out so that the file processes correctly.

```
import csv,time,string,os,requests, json
from datetime import datetime
import unidecode, unicodedata

def clean(text):
    #attempt 1
    if (type(text) is str):
        text = unicodedata.normalize('NFD',unicode(text)).encode('ascii','ignore')
        return text
    else:
        return text

    #attempt 2
    if text is not None:
        try:
            text.decode('ascii')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            print("not unicode")
            return ''
        else:
            print("unicode")
            return text

with open(input_file) as infile, open("c:\\upload\\output_file.csv", "wb") as outfile:
    r = csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter=",", skipinitialspace=True)
    w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, inv_fields, extrasaction="ignore")
    r = [{k: clean(v) for k, v in row.items()} for row in r]

    wtr = csv.writer( outfile )    
    wtr.writerow(["a", "b", "c", "f"])
    rows_processed = 0
    for i, row in enumerate(r, start=new_start_row):
        rows_processed += 1
        print("Starting row " + str(rows_processed))
        row['id'] = i
        w.writerow(row)
```

If I remove the arrow character from the cell, save, and re-run the script, it works fine, so I know it's this character that's causing the script to fail.  My initial thought is to run each cell through a filter, with this line of code:

`r = [{k: clean(v) for k, v in row.items()} for row in r]`

but I can't seem to write anything that will "find" this bad character. On the screen I'll see `Starting row 1/2/3/4/5` and then on row 6, where this cell exists, the script will stop running.  I do not get any error or any Traceback, it just finishes.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you find out the numerical code of that specific arrow? Look in the datafile with a good hex editor.

Comment: this is it: https://unicodelookup.com/#26/1

Comment: Ha. That site is wrong (control codes do not have a defined image in Unicode) but it indeed confirms my suspicion the "arrow" is not a straight Unicode character. Code 26 a.k.a. `Ctrl+Z` is a remnant of days past: End Of File. I wonder what part of Python's libraries fell for that. Try opening the file not as Text but as Binary.

Comment: Couldn't I just replace Unicode Character 26 with a blank?  Not sure how to do your suggestion or mine though..

Comment: Opening a file in binary mode, you mean? Doesn't DictReader like that?

Comment: oh nm - I just change it to `open(input_file, "rb")` - sweet - that worked!

Comment: To the OP as well as @RadLexus: http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_arrows.html is a helpful site for identifying unicode characters, even if it would not have been of help in solving this particular problelm.

Comment: @BillBell: if this arrow had been Unicode, then (I guess) Python's file handling for text ought not have a problem with it. The problem was that it's an arrow *in an old DOS font*. Nothing Unicode about that. (I prefer [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/arrows/list.htm), by the way.)